# Which are the default attributes of an agent in Anylogic? What is the proper way to copy an agent?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to figure out which are the main default attributes of agents in Anylogic, e.g., the Id, the position and the index. So far I haven't found them in the help or at stackoverflow.

1) Do you know where this can be found or can you summarize the main you know? For instance the id used as unique identifier or the index used as the position inside of the population.

2) Are there any attributes regarding the agent history? For example time stamps as the creation time or the blocks it has passed through?

3) Is it possible to change the default id attribute of an agent? Can two agents have the same id?

4) As the split block doesn't copy any of the parameters or variables values to the copy, what is the proper way to copy an agent? I noticed in other publication Benjamin mentioned using agent.set_MyParam(original.MyParam). What would be "MyParam" in this code? Would this copy the value of parameters, variables and the current state in the statechart? Is it possible to make a copy and initialize its current state in the statechart as the original agent's current state?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are many things that are generated when you generate an agent... the best you can do is to check the api for the agent here: [agent api](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FAgent.html&resultof=%22%61%67%65%6E%74%22%20%22%61%70%69%22%20)
2. You can only see these things on the log if you activate it, but not from the API
3. the id is a unique identifier and i've never been in a situation where i need to change it,but if you want to change it, you can use the setId method, in which case, 2 or more agents may have the same id.
4. you can only use set_MyParam if the MyParam is a parameter, you can't do the same with variables. Nevertheless, if you want to copy an agent, you need to do it variable by variable, state by state, everything from scratch. There's no magical way to copy the exact same agent with all its current values and states and connections etc